# Como fazer subconsulta com pdo

Tags: php, pdo, query, select

Gostaria de realizar uma subconsulta dentro dessa query:

```
$ranking = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios_emblemas GROUP BY usuario ORDER BY count(usuario) DESC LIMIT 3");
```

Seria para bloquear a listagem de usuários com banido=true, ou seja quero fazer essa mesma query acima porém que não liste usuarios com banido=true.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Edit: A coluna "banido" fica na tabela "usuarios".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que utilizar o `JOIN` para interligar as duas tabelas e fazer a comparação:

```
$ranking = $pdo->query("
    SELECT * FROM usuarios a
    INNER JOIN usuarios_emblemas b ON a.usuario = b.usuario
    WHERE a.banido <> true
    GROUP BY a.usuario
    ORDER BY count(a.usuario) DESC
    LIMIT 3
");
```

Conforme você pediu nos comentários, segue o `SELECT` para pegar os autores:

```
$ranking = $pdo->query("
    SELECT * FROM usuarios a
    INNER JOIN topicos_comentarios b ON a.usuario = b.autor
    WHERE NOT a.banido
    GROUP BY a.usuario
    ORDER BY count(a.usuario) DESC
    LIMIT 3
");
```

Comment: Não. A coluna banido fica em outra tabela, chamada usuarios.

Comment: Qual o nome da outra tabela? E qual a coluna que liga as duas tabelas?

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi a pergunta.

Comment: Nessa tabela `usuario_emblemas`, provavelmente tem o `id` da tabela `usuarios` ou algum outro campo que liga as duas tabelas, qual o nome desse campo? Se não tiver um campo com esse intuito não será possível fazer a ligação.

Comment: Se eu entendi a pergunta, seria o campo usuario. A query que estou utilizando conta quantos valores existem com o usuario=x.

Comment: Confira as imagens: Tabela usuarios: https://prnt.sc/fs0vor || Tabela usuarios_emblemas: http://prntscr.com/fs0w0y

Comment: Era isso mesmo, alterei a minha resposta, verifique se funciona da forma que você espera.

Comment: Poderia me ajudar novamente porém com essa query a seguir: $ranking = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM topicos_comentarios GROUP BY autor ORDER BY count(autor) DESC LIMIT 3");

Comment: Ficaria muito grato.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo :x

Comment: O campo `autor` da tabela `topicos_comentarios` é a mesma coisa que o campo `usuario` da tabela `usuarios` ?

Comment: Sim. É o mesmo.

Comment: Esta alterada a resposta

Comment: O segundo exemplo não funcionou. Os usuários banidos continuam sendo listados.

Comment: Estrutura da tabela topicos_comentarios: https://prnt.sc/fs1l1r

Comment: Valores: https://prnt.sc/fs1lbq

Comment: Tente com a alteração que eu fiz agora. Estranho não funcionar, o `SELECT` é o mesmo, só muda a tabela do `JOIN`

Comment: Dessa vez não exibiu nada.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61623/discussion-between-roberto-fagundes-and-paulo-sergio-filho).

Answer (score 3):

Só dar um `join` com a tabela de usuários:

```
SELECT 
e.* 
FROM usuarios_emblemas e
inner join usuarios u on u.id = e.usuario and not u.banido
GROUP BY e.usuario ORDER BY count(e.usuario) DESC LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Existem N maneiras de selecionar duas ou mais tabelas, vou citar dois exemplos:

**Exemplo 1:**

```
$ranking = $pdo->query("SELECT ue.id, ue.nome, u.banido FROM usuarios_emblemas ue, usuarios u where (ue.id_usuario = u.id) and (u.banido = 0)/*Continuação*/");
```

**Exemplo 2:**

```
$ranking = $pdo->query("SELECT ue.id, ue.nome, u.banido FROM usuarios_emblemas ue LEFT JOIN usuarios u on (ue.id_usuario = u.id) where (u.banido = 0)/*Continuação*/");
```

Dica: Se você gosta de utilizar asterisco (*) e possui muitos campos nas tabelas, você terá um resultado mais lento, pois o "select" irá trazer todos os campos desnecessários para a consulta.